# SQLite - Select posts based on tags

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in my database: posts, which contains post id and other informations, and tags. In tags, there is a column post_id and a column tag. My idea is to store each tag in a separate row. For instance, a post with id 1 and tags foo, bar and eggs would be stored in tags as

```
post_id | tag
---------------
1       | foo
1       | bar
1       | eggs
```

Which is the simplest way to get the id of a post with these three tags from the database?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aggregation.

If you want the `post_id`s that have these 3 tags and no others:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING SUM(tag IN ('foo', 'bar', 'eggs')) = 3 -- or COUNT(*) = 3
   AND SUM(tag NOT IN ('foo', 'bar', 'eggs')) = 0
```

If you want the `post_id`s that have these 3 tags and maybe other tags too then it is simpler:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM tags
WHERE tag IN ('foo', 'bar', 'eggs')
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

I assume that each combination of `post_id` and `tag` is unique.